# How do I take a Public Key String and turn it into a Pycryptodome key (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, public-key-encryption, pycryptodome

I have a public key, however, I'm not sure on how to turn that into a key on Pycryptodome. I've been using this code that I found [here](http://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/examples.html)

```
keyDER = b64decode(key64)
seq = asn1.DerSequence()
seq.decode(keyDER)
keyPub = RSA.construct((seq[0], seq[1]))

print(keyPub.encrypt('test',"Unguessable"))
```

With key64 as the PublicKey, however, I get `ValueError: Unexpected DER tag`. Is there a better way of doing this in python 3.6 with Pycryptodome?

Comment: Try inspecting the source of Pycryptodome and see if you can reuse some of the code.

Comment: I would if I knew what I was doing, but truth be told, I'm not too familiar with RSA and other types of encryption. I know how it works and etc, however, I just need to figure this out as part of bigger project I'm doing. However, if somone would like to explain RSA a little more indefinably, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We need these modules:

```
import os
from Cryptodome.Hash import SHA256
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA
from Cryptodome.Signature import pkcs1_15
```

We have a plantext:

```
message = b'hello!'
```

Find a hash from plaintext:

```
h = SHA256.new(message)
```

Generate random key:

```
key = RSA.generate(1024, os.urandom)
```

Create a signature:

```
signature = pkcs1_15.new(key).sign(h)
```

And finally take a public key:

```
pub_key = key.publickey()
```

The check func will look like this:

```
 def sign(message, pubkey, signature):
      h = SHA256.new(message)
      try:
          pkcs1_15.new(pubkey).verify(h, signature)
          print('Success!')
      except ValueError:
          print('Invalid signature!')
```